# CSS background image only working in firefox

Tags: css, cross-browser, background-image

On a search button I created a background image which shows only in firefox and not in other browsers (checked Chrome, IE and Opera).

This is my HTML (generated by Joomla):

```
<input class="button" type="image" onclick="this.form.searchword.focus();" src="/dev/" value="Search">
```

And here is my CSS:

```
#search .search .button{
    background: #1B3F8B url('../images/search_btn.png') no-repeat center center;
    border:1px solid #1B3F8B;
    width:22px;
    height:32px;
    float:right;
}
```

My image is a RGB .png

The weird thing is that I see it loaded in Google Chrome but after half a second it disappears and it shows the regular 'image not loaded' image.

I can't seem to find any answers to this problem, anybody have any experience with this problem or knows what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change `type="image"` to `type="button"`.  Since the background image is in the css class you can remove the `src` from the HTML markup also.

The markup would look like:

```
<input class="button" type="button" onclick="this.form.searchword.focus();" value="Search">
```

You also need to update your CSS to add commas:

```
#search, .search, .button{
```

Comment: It was an option in Joomla itself but your answer was basicly what that option did. CSS is fine as it is though, when I add commas it hasn't got the desired outcome.

Answer (score 1):

You need commas delimiting the selectors in your CSS.  You still need to remove the `src="/dev/"`, I think.

```
#search, .search, .button {
    background : url('../images/search_btn.png') center center no-repeat #1B3F8B;
    border : #1B3F8B solid 1px;
    width : 22px;
    height : 32px;
    float : right;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/M5BaR/1/